# Need advice unit testing code that is untestable

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm in a bit of a bind.

We have some PHP production code written by a developer that needs to be refactored. However, it has zero tests. So, I'm afraid to refactor it.

I have been writing unit tests but a lot of the code depends on $_GET params when it should be using the Request class (it was built in Lumen).

So, running unit tests is impossible.

What are my options here? I could edit the code so that $_GET is no longer used but the way the code is structure, it's very risky to do that.

The funny thing is, we want to write tests so that we can refactor, but it seems that in order to be able to write tests, I have to do some refactoring anyway.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `"but it seems that in order to be able to write tests, I have to do some refactoring anyway"` - Pretty much, yes.  If the code wasn't designed to be testable, then it needs to be modified in order to be testable.

Comment: You can force `$_GET` values.

Comment: David, that's what I'm dreading.

@JonStirling, how would you suggest I do that?

Comment: `$_GET['mykey'] = 'somevalue'` in your setup?

Comment: I don't think that will work unless I add that to the code that I'm actually testing. That information should originate from the unit test though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to start with integration or acceptance tests. Then you have something in place that gives you a little bit of confidence to rewrite the code so that it can be tested with unit tests. Unfortunately, it is possible to write code that can not be unit tested.

Have a look at "Outside-in testing".

Comment: This sounds like the most plausible solution. I was seriously considering it but I wanted to see if there are better alternatives.

Outside-in testing: I'm going to go Google that.

Answer (score 0):

Just some wild thoughts. Is that possible to write unit test in a way that it can abstract the request type, i mean, to write a base class, say RequestBase, then a child class of that to wrap Request class (LumenRequest) ,  and another child class (LegacyRequest) to wrap $_GET, so that they have the same interface. With old code, you run the test with LegacyRequest, and with new code, you run it with LumenRequest

Comment: I'd still have to refactor to do this.
Here's the thing, the router calls a controller method which then calls some other classes. It's not just inheritance, there are actual controllers that are instantiated from other controllers.